# Why does Chrome Mobile cancels setPointerCapture? How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile

I call `setPointerCapture` in response to a `pointerdown` event. A few messages (like 6) later, Chrome cancels the pointer capture, sending a `pointercancel` event. Why is it cancelling the captured pointer?  What is the proper way to capture the pointer so this doesn't happen?

(I'm using the Chrome desktops' mobile emulation mode for testing.)

Comment: Duplicate. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524422/setpointercapture-does-not-apprear-to-be-working-on-google-chrome